# Project one field from specific object element in an array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I have a collection:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "_deleted": false,
    "customFields": [{
        "fieldName": "sapID",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "fieldName": "salesTerritory",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "fieldName": "clientType",
        "value": "Corporate"
    }],
}
```

How can I `project(aggregate)` only the `value` field of the element with `fieldName = "clientType"`:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
        $project:{value:<code>}
    }
)
```

I tried `$filter` but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "customFields.value": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2LzFwr1tNPB)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      customFields: {
        $map: {
          input: "$customFields",
          as: "c",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { "$eq": [ "$$c.fieldName", "clientType" ] },
              then: { value: "$$c.value" },
              else: "$$c"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BOieIglaju3)

Comment: Thank you! But you miss the condition `fieldName = "clientType"`

Comment: @TiếnAnhDương I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         customFields: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$customFields",
               $cond: { $eq: ["$$this.fieldName", "clientType"] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JLi7NWnBD3m)